# How I can limit and relate the two options listed in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Hi I have 3 tables in my database:
prospects
Areas
careers
Adding a prospect want the user to select an area and a career that belongs to it. As the races I can limit the controller to only show me the area and not all careers database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use containable to limit the data in finds http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('Relation1', 'Relation3')
));
```